# Jenkins Failed To Start

Tags: centos7, jenkins

Jenkins failed to start after disk space going out. After deleting data start the Jenkins but it start for few seconds and down again.

```
    jenkins.service - Jenkins Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2019-05-21 13:14:01 IST; 3s ago
  Process: 12835 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins.war --httpPort=9090 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
 Main PID: 12835 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

May 21 13:14:00 appdevjava java[12835]: INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
May 21 13:14:00 appdevjava java[12835]: May 21, 2019 1:14:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
May 21 13:14:00 appdevjava java[12835]: WARNING: Empty contextPath
May 21 13:14:00 appdevjava java[12835]: May 21, 2019 1:14:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
May 21 13:14:00 appdevjava java[12835]: INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
May 21 13:14:01 appdevjava java[12835]: May 21, 2019 1:14:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
May 21 13:14:01 appdevjava java[12835]: INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
May 21 13:14:01 appdevjava systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 21 13:14:01 appdevjava systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
May 21 13:14:01 appdevjava systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

Comment: please use "journalctl -u jenkins.service" to see clearly what happened? then we can continue. also are you sure kill all of Jenkin ?.

Comment: Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
 WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
 INFO: Logging initialized @1578ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
  winstone.Logger logInternal
 INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
  PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
 WARNING: Empty contextPath
  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
 INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT